# java socket not work and redundant code required for participial work

Tags: java, sockets

I want to send 200 x 200 arrays (4 int each "line") from server to client.
But I must add that to server, to client receive all data

```
while(true){
    Bw.write("end");
    Bw.write("\n");
}
```

Without it client receive only first 194 x 200 and 1 x 32, then receive no mo data.

What I must do to it work without waiting for exception in while(true)?

Server:

```
ServerSocket ssocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
Socket socket = ssocket.accept();
BufferedWriter Bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
//load from XML 
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
File xmlFile = new File("res/map.xml");
Document doc = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
Element root = doc.getRootElement();

int sz = root.getAttribute("sizeZ").getIntValue();
int sx = root.getAttribute("sizeX").getIntValue();
data = new float[sz][sx];
data2 = new int[sz][sx];
Bw.write(String.valueOf(sz));
Bw.write(" ");
Bw.write(String.valueOf(sx));
Bw.write("\n");
for(Object o : root.getChildren()){
    Element e = (Element) o;
    int z = e.getAttribute("z").getIntValue();
    int x = e.getAttribute("x").getIntValue();
    int y = e.getAttribute("y").getIntValue();
    int g = (int)e.getAttribute("g").getFloatValue();
    data[z][x] = y;
    data2[z][x] = g;
    Bw.write(String.valueOf(z));
    Bw.write(" ");
    Bw.write(String.valueOf(x));
    Bw.write(" ");
    Bw.write(String.valueOf(y));
    Bw.write(" ");
    Bw.write(String.valueOf(g));
    Bw.write("\n");
}
Bw.write("end");
Bw.write("\n");
while(true){
    Bw.write("end");
    Bw.write("\n");
}
```

Client:

```
socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1080);
System.out.println("úspěšné připojení");
socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

String[] s;
String st;
st = Br.readLine();
System.out.println(st);
s = st.split(" ");
data = new float[Integer.parseInt(s[0])][Integer.parseInt(s[1])];
data2 = new int[Integer.parseInt(s[0])][Integer.parseInt(s[1])];
st = Br.readLine();
s = st.split(" ");
while(!s[0].equals("end")){
    int z = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
    int x = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
    int g = Integer.parseInt(s[3]);
    data[z][x] = y;
    data2[z][x] = g;
    st = Br.readLine();
    s = st.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking here. What's `while(true)` for?

Comment: while(true){
    Bw.write("end");
    Bw.write("\n");
}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call `bw.flush()` when you've finished writing (real) data.

---

And while I have your attention, these are bad style:

```
  BufferedReader Br =                     // should be br
  BufferedWriter Bw =                     // should be bw
```

and your both your client and server-side code looks like it could leak file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks, I try it before, but I must have something else wrong, now it works.